# remove the key value if a column is repeated and taking only the first one in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested

**Input:** I have a dictionary in this form with a lot more data

```
d = {
    'ag': pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1', 'id1', 'id1'], 'name': ['a', 's', 'd'], 'num': [10, 7, 2]}),
    'jk': pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id2', 'id2', 'id2'], 'name': ['w', 'r', 'y'], 'num': [15, 8, 1]}),
    'rp': pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1', 'id1'], 'name': ['f', 'n'], 'num': [13, 11]})
}
```

**Expected Output:** I want to remove the key value from dictionary(d), if the ID(id1) is repeated again in next key(rp).

```
d = {
    'ag': pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1', 'id1', 'id1'], 'name': ['a', 's', 'd'], 'num': [10, 7, 2]}),
    'jk': pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id2', 'id2', 'id2'], 'name': ['w', 'r', 'y'], 'num': [15, 8, 1]})
    
}
```

**code I tried:**

```
new_d = {}

unique_ids = set()

for key in sorted(d.keys()):
    key_ids = set(d[key]['ID'].tolist())
    if not(key_ids & unique_ids):
        new_d[key] = d[key]
    unique_ids |= key_ids

print(new_d)
```

I need a different approach, this is not giving me good results for a large dataset.

Comment: what do you mean by `ID(id1) is repeated again in next key(rp)`?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a function to do the task

```
def remove_duplicate_key(d):

  #  'dt' temp variable to iterate over
  dt=d.copy()
  for i, key in zip(range(len(dt)), dt.keys()):
    var = 'id'+str(i+1)
    temp_df=dt.get(key, None)
    if temp_df['ID'].value_counts().index[0]!=var:
       d.pop(key, None)
       print(d)
    else:
       continue
  return d
```

Its creating the `variable var='id'+str(i)` since `id` is anyway incrementing. Then call the function `remove_duplicate_key(d)`

Comment: the id in here is just for example, it can be different. Thus cat use this method